# Using Redis to store array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, redis, hash

I have just started to look at Redis and would like to be able to store an Array of hashes, where I can pop a random key/value out and then put it back in when I need to.

So in Ruby I would have something like this

```
users = [{ username: "user1", password: "password"}, { username: "user2", password: 'password'}]
```

So if I wanted to get a random key/value object from the Array I would do something like this

```
@user = users.shuffle!.pop
```

And then to put it  back into the array

```
users.push(@user)
```

The idea for using Redis is that I have two processes (Ruby based app) that need to share a pool of users at the same time. Once a process has finished with a user I want it to put it back into the pool.

What can I try next?

Comment: If I understand correctly, You need to pull a Key/Value pair from Redis at random, and block it, i.e. no other process could use it until the process 1 is finished?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could [Redis Hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) to store a user info and [Redis Set](http://redis.io/commands#set) to store all these hashes together.

Steps:

1. Make a redis Hash with HSET command:`HMSET userId_653 username "Tom" password "gd36e3hd38d3jdj3yd3hd38"`
2. Add this hash in the set called users: `SADD users userId_653`. This set contains all the users.
3. Get a random user key from the set: `SRANDMEMBER users`. It will return **userId_653**
4. Get the corresponding values from hash using `HGET userId_653 username`
5. If you need to pop the key simply do `SPOP users` after step 3. and `SADD` again after processing in step 4.

A similar question for better understanding: [Redis how to store associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001247/redis-how-to-store-associative-array-set-or-hash-or-list)

References:

- http://redis.io/commands/srandmember
- http://redis.io/commands/sadd
- http://redis.io/commands/spop
- http://redis.io/commands/hget
- http://redis.io/commands/hmset

PS: I have no experience in Ruby. Look for suitable Redis Ruby API which would support all these operations!

Comment: thanks for your answer, after i have finished with the random user i can just SET the hash again and add it back to users? The idea being the set just gets repopulated once a user has been finished with.. Think i get it all though, those references will help

Comment: No need to set the hash again. If you are not editing user Info. As all your processes will access users from set, simply popping and adding in the set will suffice :)